# Unable to redirect http to https using Express and React as frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, https

I am writing a web application using Node/Express for backend and React for frontend. They are sitting on the same server and I use /api to differentiate the web pages vs api services. However, I am having trouble redirecting all my traffic to https from http. I've narrowed it down to a problem that my code is rendering its frontend calls to static pages:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

// Redirect all traffic to https
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('req start: ',req.secure, req.hostname, req.url, 
  app.get('port'));
  if (req.secure) {
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname + ':' + app.get('secPort') + req.url);
});


// Allow browserHistory
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
})
```

So I am assuming that the reason why it's not redirecting to https is that it is sending a html file on the server instead of serving the actual webapp. I was wondering if any of you have any insights on how to go about this, whether I need to separate the webapp from my api services, or is it something I can change within React?

Comment: try using the redirect function before the express.static call for the public files.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!